# Why do I need a double semicolon in some statements outside the toplevel

Tags: ocaml

I have the following two lines of code:

```
let a = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0]
print_string (String.concat " " (List.map string_of_int a))
```

It gives me this error:

> File "test.ml", line 65, characters 0-0:
> Error: Syntax error

However, if I end the line with a double semicolon:

```
let a = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0];;
print_string (String.concat " " (List.map string_of_int a))
```

it works fine.

I've read, double semicolon should only be used in the top level, so why do I need it here. If I don't, what should I have written instead?

Comment: You only really need them in the REPL, not in files...

Answer (score 4):

Double semicolons can be used to introduce a toplevel expression:

```
let x = 0
let do_something () = Printf.printf "x=%d" x
;; do_something ()
;; do_something ()
```

Here without the separating `;;` the first `do_something ()` would still be part of the definition of the function `do_something.

It is generally considered more idiomatic to use an unit toplevel binding:

```
let x = 0
let do_something () = Printf.printf "x=%d" x
let () =
  do_something (); do_something ()
```

Comment: So I should've written `let a = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0]
let () = print_string (String.concat " " (List.map string_of_int a))` instead?

Comment: yes. It's usually needed just in one place in the program, for the entrypoint: `let main () = (* do all the things *) ... let () = main ()`

Comment: The 2 things to understand are that `;;` separates toplevel *phrases*, and that you never need it, except when playing with the interactive toplevel loop.
A phrase is either: **(1)** an arbitrarily long sequence of global let-definitions, type definitions, module definitions, etc. or **(2)** a single expression, or **(3)** a special directive (like `#require "somepackage"`). In a typical compiled source code you *never* use `;;` as you usually write a single phrase of kind (1), possibly using the `let () = …` idiom for executing things. Kinds (2) and (3) are for the interactive toplevel.