# How to append a List to a List in OCaml

Tags: list, linked-list, ocaml

I want to **append** the following lists:

```
open Printf
open Format
let l1 = [[0;0];[1;1]]
let l2 = [2;2]
let l3 = l1 @ [ l2 ]
List.iter (fun ll -> printlist ll) l3
```

l1 should be `l1 = [[0;0];[1;1];[2;2]]`

But whenever I try to run the code it retrieves the following error:

```
File "array.ml", line 70, characters 5-7:
70 | l1 @ l2
          ^^
Error: This expression has type int list
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

Comment: The issue is the same as with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67136999). OCaml syntax is *not* sensitive to line breaks. Toplevel items are separated either by `;;`, or by some keywords such as `open` or `let` (global lets, not `let … in`). In your sample code, you have the following toplevel items: `open Printf` then `open Format` then `let l1 = [[0;0];[1;1]]` then `let l2 = [2;2] l1 @ [ l2 ] List.iter (fun ll -> printlist ll) l1`. The last one does not make sense, hence the type error (again the error message does not match the code you are showing us).

Comment: @Maëlan How it does not match if it is literally what it returned.

Comment: The code you gave us gives me an error on a different location (on `[2;2]`). I don’t see `l1 @ l2` anywhere in the code you gave us.

Comment: @Maëlan ?, that really doesn't matter do you know how to append two dimensional lists and then print it?

Comment: Well… That matters because that is your error. I explained the error. If you solve the error, you will succeed in appending two lists. The error is basic OCaml syntax, it has nothing to do with lists. (If you thought the error did not matter, why having reported it to begin with?)

Comment: [See also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692113/why-do-i-need-a-double-semicolon-in-some-statements-outside-the-toplevel/66692306#comment118002109_66692306)

Comment: @Maëlan, Sorry I didn't understand what you were trying to explain and still don't. I'm very new to this language and I hate it, there is little documentation online or examples. The syntax seems like it was made on mars.

Comment: In OCaml, a let binding `let name = value` will naturally break from the previous expression. Other things like `type`, `module`, and `exception` will do the same. Your call to `List.iter` does not do that. So the compiler sees this: `let l3 = l1 @ [ l2 ] List.iter (fun ll -> printlist ll) l3` as being all one thing. It's possible to workaround this by creating another let binding: `let () = List.iter (fun ll -> printlist ll) l3`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the solution to the problem, provided by ChrisDutton

```
open Printf
open Format
open List
let l1 = [[0;0];[1;1]]
let l2 = [2;2]
let l3 = l1 @ [ l2 ]

let () =
  List.iter (fun l -> List.iter print_int l) l3
```